# How to parse the following xml using DOM parser?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

How to parse the following xml using DOM parser - the `name` node is repeating up to n level

```
<Services>
    <service name ="qwerty" id="">
    <File rootProfile="abcd" extension="acd">
    <Columns>
    <name id="0" profileName="DATE" type="java"></name>
    <name id="1" profileName="DATE" type="java"></name>
    .
    .
    .
    <Columns>
    </File>
    <File rootProfile="efg" extension="ghi">
    <Columns>
    <name id="a" profileName="DATE" type="java"></name>
    <name id="b" profileName="DATE" type="java"></name>
    .
    .
    .
    <Columns>
    </File>
    </service>
    </Services>
```

I used the following code to get the values:

```
public static void xmlEditor() throws SAXException, IOException {
    try {
        File xmlFile = new File("config/ServiceConfig.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = null;

        documentBuilder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nodeList0 = doc.getElementsByTagName("Service");
        NodeList nodeList1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("File");
        NodeList nodeList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");
        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        for (int temp0 = 0; temp0 < nodeList0.getLength(); temp0++) {
            Node node0 = nodeList0.item(temp0);

            System.out.println("\nElement type :" + node0.getNodeName());
            Element Service = (Element) node0;

            if (node0.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                System.out.println("-----------------" + temp0 + "----------------------------------");
                System.out.println("name : " + Service.getAttribute("name"));
                System.out.println("id : " + Service.getAttribute("id"));


                for (int temp = 0; temp < nodeList1.getLength(); temp++) {
                    Node node1 = nodeList1.item(temp);

                    System.out.println("\nElement type :" + node1.getNodeName());

                    Element File = (Element) node1;

                    if (node1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                        System.out.println("rootProfile:" + File.getAttribute("rootProfile"));
                        System.out.println("extension  : " + File.getAttribute("extension"));


                        for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < nodeList2.getLength(); temp1++) {
                            Node node2 = nodeList2.item(temp1);

                            System.out.println("\nElement type :" + node2.getNodeName());

                            Element name = (Element) node2;

                            if (node2.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                                System.out.println("id:" + name.getAttribute("id"));
                                System.out.println("profileName  : " + name.getAttribute("profileName"));
                                System.out.println("type  : " + name.getAttribute("type"));

                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

And am getting first level of node `File` itself am getting all valus of `name` including next file node help to avoid this
the output am getting is

```
name:-----
id  :-----

rootProfile:--------
 extension:-----------

id:o
profileName:
type:
id:1
profileName:
type:
id:a
profileName:
type:
id:b
profileName:
rootProfile:--------
 extension:-----------

id:o
profileName:
type:
id:1
profileName:
type:
id:a
profileName:
type:
id:b
profileName:
```

Answer (score 1):

Complete example is posted. you may have to read the XML from File instead of String which i have used.

```
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class MyTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException,
            ParserConfigurationException {
        xmlEditor();
    }

    public static void xmlEditor() throws SAXException, IOException,
            ParserConfigurationException {
        // File xmlFile = new File("ServiceConfig.xml");
        String xml = "<Services><service name=\"qwerty\" id=\"\"><File rootProfile=\"abcd\" extension=\"acd\"><Columns>"
                + "<name id=\"0\" profileName=\"DATE\" type=\"java\"></name><name id=\"1\" profileName=\"DATE\" type=\"java\"></name>"
                + "</Columns></File><File rootProfile=\"efg\" extension=\"ghi\"><Columns><name id=\"a\" profileName=\"DATE\" type=\"java\"></name>"
                + "<name id=\"b\" profileName=\"DATE\" type=\"java\"></name></Columns></File></service></Services>";
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = null;

        documentBuilder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // org.w3c.dom.Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes())));

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nodeList0 = doc.getElementsByTagName("service");
        NodeList nodeList1 = null;
        NodeList nodeList2 = null;
        System.out.println("Root element :"
                + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        for (int temp0 = 0; temp0 < nodeList0.getLength(); temp0++) {
            Node node0 = nodeList0.item(temp0);

            System.out.println("\nElement type :" + node0.getNodeName());
            Element Service = (Element) node0;

            if (node0.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                System.out.println("-----------------" + temp0
                        + "----------------------------------");
                System.out.println("name : " + Service.getAttribute("name"));
                System.out.println("id : " + Service.getAttribute("id"));
                nodeList1 = Service.getChildNodes();
                for (int temp = 0; temp < nodeList1.getLength(); temp++) {
                    Node node1 = nodeList1.item(temp);

                    System.out
                            .println("\nElement type :" + node1.getNodeName());

                    Element File = (Element) node1;

                    if (node1.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                        System.out.println("rootProfile:"
                                + File.getAttribute("rootProfile"));
                        System.out.println("extension  : "
                                + File.getAttribute("extension"));

                        nodeList2 = File.getChildNodes();// colums
                        for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < nodeList2.getLength(); temp1++) {
                            Element column = (Element) nodeList2.item(temp1);
                            NodeList nodeList4 = column.getChildNodes();
                            for (int temp3 = 0; temp3 < nodeList4.getLength(); temp3++) {
                                Element name = (Element) nodeList4.item(temp3);
                                if (name.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                                    System.out.println("id:"
                                            + name.getAttribute("id"));
                                    System.out.println("profileName  : "
                                            + name.getAttribute("profileName"));
                                    System.out.println("type  : "
                                            + name.getAttribute("type"));

                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Output:

> Root element :Services
>
> Element type :service
>   -----------------0---------------------------------- name : qwerty id :
>
> Element type :File rootProfile:abcd extension  : acd id:0 profileName 
>   : DATE type  : java id:1 profileName  : DATE type  : java
>
> Element type :File rootProfile:efg extension  : ghi id:a profileName 
>   : DATE type  : java id:b profileName  : DATE type  : java